# $[G:Z(G)] = n$ prove that each conjugacy class has at most n elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, normal-subgroups

$[G:Z(G)] = n$ prove that each conjugacy class has at most n elements.

what i tried -

I know from the orbit stabiliser theorem that

$|G| = \sum_{x_i} |G:C(x_i)| + |Z(G)|$

Because Z(G) < G i also know from Lagrange theorem that:

$|G| = |Z(G)| * [G:Z(G)] = |Z(G)| * n$

i know that the size of each conjugacy class is $|G:C(x_i)|$

here I'm stuck.. any help will be appreciated

Comment: What is a "conjugacy group"? Conjugacy classes do not form subgroups (except the conjugacy class of identity, which is the trivial subgroup).

Comment: $Z(G) \leq C(x_i)$ Implies that $[G : C(x_i)] \leq [G:Z(G)]$.

Comment: so Conjugacy class are not subgroups?

Comment: N.S - why is Z(G) < C(xi)?

Comment: $C(x_i)$ is the set of all $g\in G$ that commutes with $x_i$. On the other hand $Z(G)$ is the set of all elements that commute with everything, in particular with $x_i$.

Answer (score 5):

Ok ,

so from looking at the comments -

$Z(G)≤C(x_i) $Implies that $[G:C(x_i)]≤[G:Z(G)]$

so because

$[G:Z(G)]=n$

we get -

$[G:C(x_i)]≤  n$

thanks N.S. for the help

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{Proof:} \, \text{We know} $ $G/Z(G) \cong \text{Inn}(G)$. Since $G$ is finite, $n=|G:Z(G)|= \frac{|G|}{|Z(G)|}=|\text{Inn}(G)|$ by Lagrange's Theorem. So, there are $n$ distinct inner automorphisms $\theta_{g_i}$ where $g_i \in G$ for $i=1,...,n$. Let $x \in G$, then $\text{cl}(x)=\{g^{-1}xg | g \in G\}=\{\theta_{g_i}(x) | g_i \in G \,\, \text{for}\,\, i=1,...,n\}$. Then $|\text{cl}(x)| \leq n$.